# Avoid Spring Boot App to connect to Cassandra on boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have a Spring Boot Application which stores/retries data from Cassandra DB. But if Cassandra is not available, Spring application does not boot.

Here is my code - https://github.com/simplyatul/springcassandrajunit

I am playing around DemoTableRepo.java. If I comment out

```
@RepositoryDefinition(domainClass = DemoTable.class, idClass = String.class)
```

then Spring boot app starts w/o connecting to Cassandra, however when Repo is used on retrieve/store call it throws following exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Interface org.simplyatul.cassandrajunit.repository.DemoTableRepo must be annotated with @org.springframework.data.repository.RepositoryDefinition!
```

If I keep the following line commented

```
@RepositoryDefinition(domainClass = DemoTable.class, idClass = String.class)
```

then Spring boot app tries to connect to Cassandra on boot and fails to start.

I found similar links/Qs, but things are not working with the solutions provided. Am I missing anything? Thanks in advance.

[How can we stop spring boot data cassandra from connecting to localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41281144/how-can-we-stop-spring-boot-data-cassandra-from-connecting-to-localhost/41285328)

[How to load spring application context even if Cassandra down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33745615/how-to-load-spring-application-context-even-if-cassandra-down/33784190#33784190)

Comment: try using a ConnectionPool with a reconnection policy

Comment: Thanks @MarcStröbel. I am new to Spring boot, so if you can point me to some sample code then that would be great help.